# User defined writefile function won't save output to txt file

Tags: python, file-io, writefile

I've created two functions to read and write text files as a larger part of a caeser cipher program where I need to encode and decode content from and to different text files. These are:

```
def readfile(f):
   try:
      file_object = open(f, 'r+')
      message = file_object.read()
      file_object.close()
      return message
   except:
      print("No such file or dictionary!")
      quit()
```

and

```
def writefile(message):
   try:
      f = open("file", 'a')
      f.write(message + '\n')
      f.close()
   except ValueError:
      print("No such file or dictionary!")
      quit()
   except:
      print("Input must be a string!")
      quit()
```

The problem seems to be that my write function won't actually save the program's output to the next text file. I've been stumped for sometime, could use a hand.

*EDIT* Thanks Barmar! my write function was writing to a set file that didn't exist. This worked for me:

```
def writefile(message):
   try:
      f = open(input("Please enter a file for writing:"), 'w')
      f.write(message + '\n')
      f.close()
   except ValueError:
      print("The selected file cannot be open for writing!")
      quit()
   except:
      quit()
```

Comment: It's saving to a file named `file`. Is that the correct filename? Maybe you should make the filename a function parameter, like you do for `readfile()`.

Comment: You might want to check out `with open() as f:`

Comment: Thanks Barmar that got me where I needed! Not sure how I missed that. It was trying to write to a file that did not exist. I changed the file input to be user defined.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barmar! my write function was writing to a set file that didn't exist. This worked for me:

```
def writefile(message):
   try:
      f = open(input("Please enter a file for writing:"), 'w')
      f.write(message + '\n')
      f.close()
   except ValueError:
      print("The selected file cannot be open for writing!")
      quit()
   except:
      quit()
```